# Retrieve a list of venues for a country using Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

I am new to the Foursquare API and I am trying to get a list of all places (venues) from the API for a country, I believe I read this is only for superuser 2? I am unable to find this in the developer documentation on Foursquare, can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: I found a way, in the Foursquare API URL, set the following ```intent=global``` - it will retrieve results that are not close by :)

Comment: @Supertecnoboff can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817750/create-venue-without-providing-ll

Answer (score 0):

There are *a lot* of venues in an entire country. You can't use the Foursquare API to search a region this wide. As per our [documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search), the largest radius we support searching in is 100,000 meters.

Comment: So what if the users current location is Hong Kong, but they want to search for the Eiffel Tower in paris (to learn more/etc..)?? Is there no way to search for venues not close by to the user with Foursquare?

Comment: I found a way, in the Foursquare API URL, set the following ```intent=global``` - it will retrieve results that are not close by :)