# Create venue without providing ll

Tags: foursquare, yelp

This url I am hitting for searching the venues

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=undefined%2Cundefined&query=A&limit=25&v=20170721&m=foursquare&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET
```

It gives me the near by venues but I need to get overall venues around  the world... So when I don't put the `ll` it throws error `must provide ll`

How can I search for all the venues ?

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `intent=global` param.

e.g.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?intent=global&query=A&limit=25&v=20170721&m=foursquare&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET